# Find integral $\int\limits_{0}^{5}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\left ( 5-x \right )\left ( 5+x \right )}}}{\left ( 5+x \right )\sqrt{25-x^2}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I tried to do the substitution $x=5\sin t$ but nothing worked. After this replacement, the integral only got worse ...
How do I find it?
$$\int\limits_{0}^{5}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\left ( 5-x \right )\left ( 5+x \right )}}}{\left ( 5+x \right )\sqrt{25-x^2}}dx$$

Comment: You have tried the right substitution. Use by-parts method after the substitution.

Comment: I didn't succeed ... Interesting task! This integral has no antiderivative. Maybe some method should be applied here?

Comment: I tried and got stuck too.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: simplify the integral with the substitution $x= \frac{5(1-y^2)}{1+y^2}$

$$\int\limits_{0}^{5}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\left ( 5-x \right )\left ( 5+x \right )}}}{\left ( 5+x \right )\sqrt{25-x^2}}dx
=\frac15 \int_0^1 e^{\frac{10y}{1+y^2} }dy
$$